# How can I test if a value in one row is unique comparing with all previous rows by group, and count number of different value

Tags: r

I am trying to test if value in one row is unique comparing with all previous rows by group.

For example, for `ID=1`, I want to compare the drug of the current row to all previous rows (or to day, compare to those `DATE` earlier than the current row) under `ID=1`, eg. In row 2, drug `A` is same as in row 1 , thus `EXIST_BEFORE` codes as `1` ; for row  4, `C` is unique comparing with previous rows (`A`, `B` , `C`) thus codes as `0`.

add another question: how can I count the number of different `drug`  prior the current `date` ?  for example, for `ID=1` , `prev_drug` for row 4 is `2` , because it has two drugs ( A ,B) different from drug C prior the the `DATE` of row 4.

```
ID  DATE       DRUG EXIST_BEFORE  prev_drug
1   2001-01-01  A   NA            0
1   2001-02-01  A   1             0
1   2001-03-15  B   0             1
1   2001-04-20  C   0             2
1   2001-05-29  A   1             2
1   2001-05-02  B   1             2
2   2001-03-02  A   NA            0
2   2001-03-23  C   0             1
2   2001-04-04  D   0             2
2   2001-05-05  B   0             3
```

I only know how to compare with one row above by `lag()`, but have no idea on comparing to date before for each `ID`.

Comment: You are looking for the function `duplicated`, applied per group

Comment: Please provide the expected outcome.

Comment: 'duplicated' presupposes the data is sorted by DATE. which is easy to do of course, but nonetheless a requirement.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein  The expected outcome is the `EXIST_BEFORE` column.

Answer (score 1):

For this, try using `dplyr`. Basically we can just group on `ID` and `DRUG`. For that grouped combination, find the first `DATE` occurrence using `min()`. Then, if the date is after that first occurrence, than it is a repeat.

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  group_by(ID, DRUG) %>%
  mutate(FIRST_OCCURANCE = min(DATE),
         EXIST_BEFORE = DATE > FIRST_OCCURANCE)

      ID DATE       DRUG  EXIST_BEFORE FIRST_OCCURANCE
   <int> <date>     <chr> <lgl>        <date>         
 1     1 2001-01-01 A     FALSE        2001-01-01     
 2     1 2001-02-01 A     TRUE         2001-01-01     
 3     1 2001-03-15 B     FALSE        2001-03-15     
 4     1 2001-04-20 C     FALSE        2001-04-20     
 5     1 2001-05-29 A     TRUE         2001-01-01     
 6     1 2001-05-02 B     TRUE         2001-03-15     
 7     2 2001-03-02 A     FALSE        2001-03-02     
 8     2 2001-03-23 C     FALSE        2001-03-23     
 9     2 2001-04-04 D     FALSE        2001-04-04     
10     2 2001-05-05 B     FALSE        2001-05-05
```

I broke it into two variables to show what is going on, but you can also reduce the `mutate()` line simply to:

```
mutate(EXIST_BEFORE = DATE > min(DATE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the `rowid()` function from the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package can be used:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[order(DATE), EXIST_BEFORE := pmin(1L, rowid(ID, DRUG) - 1L)]
DT
```

> ```
>     ID       DATE DRUG EXIST_BEFORE
>  1:  1 2001-01-01    A            0
>  2:  1 2001-02-01    A            1
>  3:  1 2001-03-15    B            0
>  4:  1 2001-04-20    C            0
>  5:  1 2001-05-29    A            1
>  6:  1 2001-05-02    B            1
>  7:  2 2001-03-02    A            0
>  8:  2 2001-03-23    C            0
>  9:  2 2001-04-04    D            0
> 10:  2 2001-05-05    B            0
> ```

`rowid(ID, DRUG) - 1L` counts the number of occurrences of `ID` and `DRUG` (kind of implied grouping) starting at 0. `pmin()` is used to cut off values greater 1. `order(DATE)` ensures that rows are sorted appropriately.

Or, as suggested in [Sotos' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255838/how-can-test-if-value-in-one-row-is-unique-comparing-with-all-previous-rows-by-g/54256835#comment95335690_54255838):

```
setDT(DT)[order(DATE), EXIST_BEFORE := as.integer(duplicated(DRUG)), by = ID][]
```

Comment: Thanks you ! find the `pmin` is helpful !